# Can't connect: No route to host -- l2ping Linux

Tags: linux, shell, networking, command-line, virtual-machine

I'm testing out `l2ping` via a Ubuntu VM on a MacOS machine, ran using UTM QEMU.

The following command:

```
sudo l2ping -s 5000 -f <my speaker's bluetooth MAC address>
```

produces

```
Can't connect: No route to host
```

Comment: The [other page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76798599/cant-connect-no-route-to-host-l2ping-linux) has now been deleted